# Repeater does not fire ItemCommand event

Tags: asp.net

I searched the web on this topic and got plenty of suggestions from every one (including other stackoverflow threads).

Finally, I thought implement as shown exactly here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemcommand(VS.71).aspx

Still frustrated.

My repeater is available in a user control and I added the user control as a web part to an existing webpartzone.  I could see all rows in the repeater (along with buttons).  Once I click the (any) button, it loses all the rows and itemcommand never fires.

I am using ASP.NET 4.0

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: `Show uz ze codeh`. Like the answer below says, might help if you paste the relevant HTML and CS for the Repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databound list controls (just like any other dynamically-created controls) need to be recreated on postback.  Do you have your Databind call within an `if (!IsPostback) {}` ?

Source code might help determine your specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

All the time, the Repeater has to be bound. Otherwise, Repeater_ItemCommand EVENT of the Repeater won't be fired.

That means:

```
     if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               BindRepeater();
            }
            else
            {
                BindRepeater();

            }
```

Comment: How is that different from simply calling `BindRepeater();`?  What is the significance of the `if`, in other words?

Comment: this was clear to me.  The if / else is unneeded, just being used as an explanation that whether or not IsPostback=true the repeater has to always be rebound.